# assign value to private member variable of a class

Tags: c++

I've been trying to assign a value to the private member of a fraction class, but I am stuck at the `ADD` function (friendship process) and getting the below error every time.

> error: 'num' was not declared in this scope

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class fraction
{
 long num;
 long den;

 public:
 fraction ();
 fraction(long,long);
 fraction(const fraction&);
~fraction();
long getnum (void);
long getDen (void);
void print  (void);
friend void add (const fraction &, const fraction &);
void sub  (fraction, fraction);
void mult (fraction, fraction);
void div  (fraction, fraction);
void inc  (fraction);
};
fraction::fraction(long l_num,long l_den )
{
  num = l_num ;
  den = l_den ;
}
fraction::fraction( )
{
  num = 0L ;
  den = 1L ;
}
fraction::fraction(const fraction& F)
{
    num=F.num;
    den=F.den;
}
fraction:: ~fraction ( )
{
//  cout<<"Destructor"<<endl;
}
long fraction::getDen (void)
{
  return den ;
}
long fraction::getnum (void)
{
  return num ;
}
void fraction:: print (void)
{
    if(den==0)
       den=1L;
    cout<<num<<"/"<<den <<endl;
}
void add( fraction &f1,  fraction &f2)
{
  num = (f1.getnum ( ) * f2.getDen ( )) + ( f1.getDen ( ) * f2.getnum ( ) );
  den = (f1.getDen ( ) * f2.getDen ( ));
}
void fraction::sub (fraction f1, fraction f2)
{
  num = (f1.getnum ( ) * f2.getDen ( )) - ( f1.getDen ( ) * f2.getnum ( ) );
  den = (f1.getDen ( ) * f2.getDen ( ));
}
void fraction::mult (fraction f1, fraction f2)
{
  num = (f1.getnum ( ) * f2.getnum ( ));
  den = (f1.getDen ( ) * f2.getDen ( ));
}
void fraction::div(fraction f1, fraction f2)
{
num = (f1.getnum ( ) * f2.getDen ( ));
den = (f1.getDen ( ) * f2.getnum ( ));
}
void fraction::inc (fraction f1)
{
  num = (f1.getnum ( )) + ( f1.getDen ( ) );
  den = (f1.getDen ( ) );
}
int main()
{
fraction f1,f2(5L,0L);
fraction f3(f2);
f1.print();
f2.print();
f3.print();

f3 = add(f3 , fraction (-7,8) );
f1 = add(f2,f3);
f1.print ();

f1 = sub(f2 , f3);
f1.print();

f1 = mult(f2, f3);
f1.print();

f1.inc ().inc().print();
f1=div(f2 , f3 );
f1.print();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Member functions in C++ can access member variables without having to explicitly specify `this.` before them. You take advantage of this in your code. However, friend functions cannot. In friend functions, you need to specify `f1.num` or `f2.num` (or whatever instance of fraction you want to change), not just `num`.

Answer (score 0):

You can design your `add` function this way:

```
fraction add( const fraction &f1,  const fraction &f2)
{
  long num = (f1.getnum ( ) * f2.getDen ( )) + ( f1.getDen ( ) * f2.getnum ( ) );
  long den = (f1.getDen ( ) * f2.getDen ( ));
  return fraction(num, den);
}
```

`add` no longer needs to be a `friend` function if used this way.

You will have to make a couple more edits to your getter functions:

```
long fraction::getDen (void) const 
{
  return den ;
}
long fraction::getnum (void) const 
{
  return num ;
}
```

Note that you are using `add` this way:

```
f1 = add(f2,f3);
```

Therefore, returning a void from `add` would not help you.

Having said this, there are other errors in your code that you should look into

Comment: When i made all the changes, I recieve Id returned 1 error

Comment: Please recheck, you may be defining one function more than once.